# Creating keyboard shortcuts for Terminal

Tags: terminal, keyboard, command-line, shortcut

Just to ensure that what I am saying is getting clearly across, I am not referring to things like iCanHazShortcut that allows you to execute a command anywhere through a keyboard shortcut.

I wanted to know if there is a way to have keyboard shortcuts that run a command in the current Terminal tab. I am fine with using 3rd-party applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of 3rd-party apps.

You can go to the Preferences Tab(Menu -> Terminal -> Preferences or `⌘,`), then go to Profiles -> Keyboard.
There you can create shortcuts. Enter your command and end with an enter.

For example, if you want to run `ls` each time you press `F1`, select F1 in the `Key` tab, and press "ls <enter>", which appears like `ls\015`.

I didn't find a way to bind characters though, but using all these keys should be enough.